# Generating an object from a more general class

Tags: java

I'm creating a program where I have an Animal class, and extending that, a 'Sheep' and 'Cow' class.
In my program, I also have a 'Farm' class that will create a new animal when 'generate()' is called. When I initialize the program, each farm is given a specific animal to generate.

I can think of several ways of doing this, but none of them seem particularly nice. One way I've come up with is to have my classes set out like this:

```
public class Farm {
    public Animal typeOfAnimalToSpawn;

    public Farm(Animal a) {
        typeOfAnimalToSpawn = a;
    }

    public void generate() {
        typeOfAnimalToSpawn.spawnMe();
    }
}

public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void spawnMe();
}

public class Sheep {
    public void spawnMe() {
        new Sheep().create();
    }

    public void create() {
        // Spawn this sheep onto the field (By making it visible or something)
        // Do whatever needs done when a sheep arrives
    }
}
```

This seems crazily complicated and convoluted for something that I can only assume has a simple and elegant solution. In this scenario, I'm actually using the Sheep both as a type (For the farm) and an object (For when it's created). On top of this, it bugs me that calling 'new Sheep()' doesn't actually create a sheep, and it's only after something calls create() that anything happens. It also doesn't feel right to store an entire instance of an animal simply to serve as a type for the farm to spawn future animals.

It would be easy enough to simply have a farm for every type of animal:

```
public abstract class Farm {
    public abstract generate();
}

public class SheepFarm extends Farm {
    public void generate() {
        new Sheep();
    }
}

public class Sheep {
    public Sheep() {
        // Do whatever needs done when a sheep arrives
    }
}
```

That's nice and neat on the surface but involves an extra, completely useless class for every new animal added to the program. Not exactly ideal either.

There is another way, with reflection, but I'm reluctant to use it as I'm sure there's some more sensible way of doing things.

*So, my question is, what's the best way to approach a situation such as this one, and is there a simpler way of doing things than the solutions I've posted above?*

I'm completely self-taught so I don't know of the proper way to do things and have had to work things out for myself with Google but it's completely failed me here; I've got no idea where to even start finding information about common programming paradigms, except, of course, for Wikipedia, which doesn't exactly come with a 'learn to write neat code' tutorial.

If my question comes off vague or even down-right nonsensical, please just ask me to clarify.

Comment: I can't even find a question in here.

Comment: Completely my fault. Forgot to actually ask anything. My question is: What's the best way to approach a situation such as this one, and is there a simpler way of doing things than the solutions I've posted above?

Comment: I am not clear on the problem statement here, why can't you simply do the same thing in option1 inside `Sheep` class whet you are doing in option2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way that I would go about it is to use generic types for `Farm` (however, you'd have to remove the abstract identifier on the `Animal` class):

```
public class Farm<E extends Animal> {

    private E e;

    public Farm() {
        this.e = (E) new Animal();
    }

    public void generate() {
        e.spawnMe();
    }

}
```

If you're not familiar with generic types, I'd definitely research them!

Comment: That's really awesome! Generic types are exactly what I was searching for! I'm still confused though, because this still requires the usage of 'new Sheep()' before the farm actually generates a sheep, forcing the sheep's constructor code to be moved to spawnMe();

Comment: @Oberdiah Yeah, unfortunately I don't think it's possible to use an abstract factory pattern to create different types of child objects, but generic types would be the way to go!

Comment: So it's common practice, and, in fact, recommended, to move the majority of initialization code, such as adding to entity lists and setting up rendering to a separate method such as createMe()?
Someone below posted something about 'new T()', which would be nice, but is not possible for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Oberdiah Initialization code should be executed in the constructor of the object being initialized.  If the initialization code is identical for every child class, then it should be done in the constructor of the abstract, parent class.

Comment: Can you quickly explain to me why, if I create a static method inside Animal called makeNoise(), I can't do E.makeNoise()? Also, thanks for the edit, but unfortunately my animal class is abstract, so that won't work

Comment: @Oberdiah I don't want to explain this incorrectly, but `E` is simply the generic object's type; Because the exact class is not known at compile-time, it can not be used to invoke static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution seems pretty efficient. I think it'd be the best way to go about it since you can just enter `Farm sheepfarm = new Farm(new Animal...)`. Good luck :)